# SetWindowLongPtr returning ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll-injection, setwindowshookex

I am still struggling with hooks.

My goal is:

- Set a hook in notepad.exe
- Subclass it (my final goal is to subclass the Edit class and show the content in my own window)

**Disclaimer**: I know there are easier ways to get the text/content from notepad, but this is a way for me to learn C, winapi, Subclassing and hooks.

My problem is that the [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) always return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED error (code 5).

**22th of May 2013: This has been fixed!
The problem was that SetWindowLongPtr was in the wrong place. It must be inside the GetMsgProc function.**

*The question became a bit long and messy, so I re-wrote the question (with updated code)*

The problem now is that GetMsgProc is **NOT** called when target is notepad.exe. If I change target to simple.exe, the GetMsgProc gets called and works!

*(Simple.exe is just a simple GUI):*

[image: Simple.exe]

The code looks like this:

**exe.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Resource.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <strsafe.h>

#include "C:\Users\Kristensen\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Win32D\dll\dllHeader.h"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HWND hWnd;

LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DLGFIRST),
        hWnd, reinterpret_cast<DLGPROC>(DlgProc));

    return FALSE;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case IDOK:
            hookNotepad();
            return TRUE;
        case IDCANCEL:
            removeHook();
            EndDialog(hWndDlg, 0);
        }
        break;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**dllHeader.h**

```
    #ifdef DLLAPI
    #else
    #define DLLAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
    DLLAPI bool hookNotepad();
    DLLAPI bool removeHook();
```

**dll.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#define DLLAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#include "dllHeader.h"

// shared variables
#pragma data_seg("Shared")
HHOOK g_hHook = NULL; // Hook for Notepad 
HWND npHWND = NULL; // Notepad handle
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:Shared,rws")

// Forward references
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) ;
LRESULT CALLBACK NewWndProc(HWND Hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
//LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) ;


LONG OldWndProc; 
DWORD pid;
HINSTANCE g_hInstDll = NULL; // DllMain entry (DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
DWORD npThreadId = NULL; // Notepad thread ID

LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) //Testing with CBTProc - same issues as with GetMsgProc.
{
    //If I hook notepad.exe, I never get called. (silence)

    //If I hook simple.exe, I get called (Beep beep!)

    // make some noise
    static DWORD dwTickKeep = 0;
    if ((GetTickCount()-dwTickKeep)>300)
    {   dwTickKeep = GetTickCount();
    Beep(2000, 100);
    }

    //Subclassing......
    //For simple.exe: (working)
    //HWND hwndEdit = ::FindWindowEx(npHWND,NULL,TEXT("WindowsForms10.RichEdit20W.app.0.2bf8098_r14_ad1"), NULL);
    //For notepad.exe: (not working)
    HWND hwndEdit = ::FindWindowEx(npHWND,NULL,TEXT("Edit"), NULL); 

    if (hwndEdit)
    {
        //Subclass it
        OldWndProc = GetWindowLongPtr(hwndEdit, GWLP_WNDPROC);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwndEdit, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)NewWndProc);
    }
    return(CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,  DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,   LPVOID lpReserved  )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        g_hInstDll = hModule;
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

bool hookNotepad ()
{
    // If target is running
    // if (npHWND = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("simpleGUI")))
    if (npHWND = FindWindow(TEXT("Notepad"), NULL))
    {
        // Finds the ThreadID for target. We use this in SetWindowsHookEx   
        npThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(npHWND, &pid); 

        // Sets the hook in target
        g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgProc, g_hInstDll, npThreadId); 
        //g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, g_hInstDll, npThreadId); 

        // If the hook succesed
        if (g_hHook) 
        { 
            ////Add a menu in the notepad.exe, but not relevant for subclassing notepads edit class...
            //HMENU hCurrent = GetMenu(npHWND); //Get the CURRENT menu of the window.
            //HMENU hNew = CreateMenu(); //Create a new one. 
            //AppendMenu(hCurrent, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (unsigned int)hNew, TEXT("myMenu")); 
            //AppendMenu(hNew, MF_STRING, 2000, L"myButton"); //2000 is the ID of the new button. 
            //DrawMenuBar(npHWND); //redraw the Menu.

            //Force a msg to the messagequeue, so that the hook function(GetMsgProc) gets called
            PostThreadMessage(npThreadId, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else
        //Notepad is not running
        return 0;
}

bool removeHook()
{
    // Removes the hook
    if (g_hHook != NULL)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hHook);
        g_hHook = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK NewWndProc(HWND Hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{ 
    //We should come here and should be able to read the text from the Edit class...
    return CallWindowProc((WNDPROC)OldWndProc, Hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

Any hints, comments or tips are highly appreciate...

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the problem, but I don't think you should be using a shared section in your DLL.  Does the call to SetWindowsHookEx succeed?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes the hook gets a return value. Everything works, except that the GetMsgProc is not called (and in here I need to set the SetWindowLongPtr to subclass the control). So the GetMsgProc  function should be a part of noptepads adress space...

Comment: Perhaps notepad is doing something unexpected?  Have you tried it on any other applications, e.g., a simple program of your own?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I have tried it on Calc (same problem), but i'll give it a shot on a simple program later. Thanks for your input so far. I'll be back :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I tried it on a simple.exe GUI. Here I works fine , except for the SetWindowLongPtr. That gives an "Unhandled exception at 0x76881F45 (usp10.dll) in simple.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x001C0FFC"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 problems in your code:

(1) The variable `HWND npHWND` is meant to be shared between the host-exe and the notepad-exe so it must be placed inside the share data segment block. This value is presently evaluated inside the 'hookNotepad' call and only exist in the host-exe only. This problem resulted in the npHWND handle being null in the notepad-exe and so the `SetWindowLongPtr` call failed.

(2) There are  2 `SetWindowLongPtr` calls, one of them is wrong. The one inside `GetMsgProc` is correct because it will be executed inside the notepad-exe context when the hook is installed. Remove the other wrong one inside `hookNotepad`.

(3) Even if (1) and (2) are resolved, the final behaviour of `SetWindowLongPtr` may not be what you expected because the main UI interactive element of the notepad-exe is the embedded edit control and not the main frame window. You should enumerate the child windows of the notepad-frame and sub-class the only one child window with `Edit` class.

Edit #1 - Add sound indicator code to check activity ------------------------------------

Add this block of code inside the `GetMsgProc`

```
// make some noise
static DWORD dwTickKeep = 0;
if ((GetTickCount()-dwTickKeep)>300)
{   dwTickKeep = GetTickCount();
    Beep(2000, 100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your valid points. GetMsgProc is still not working.

I have tried to set the hook in my own simple program, and I get a little further.
If I try to hook simple.exe, then the GetMsgProc is called!
But If I add the SetWindowLongPtr function in the  GetMsgProc function  
(This one: OldWndProc = SetWindowLongPtr(npHWND, GWLP_WNDPROC, (long)NewWndProc);)
............to be continued.....

Comment: ............
I get an error as soon as my mouse hovers over my "simpleGUI". The program freezes and I get: "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in simple.exe”
When I debug this error, I get this:
Unhandled exception at 0x76881F45 (usp10.dll) in simple.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x001C0FFC.

So far the status is:

* I still cannot get the GetMsgProc to work when hooking notepad.exe
* It works if I hook simple.exe program.
* The SetWindowLongPtr gives an Access violation (in simple.exe)

Comment: If the dll appear inside the notepad memory space as you indicated, the `GetMsgProc` should be working. The `GetMsgProc` is a very busy place as all messages routed thru it. If you have to do indication of activity, it must be simple and short, as lengthy operation, like a MessageBox may cause the message-loop to jammed up. See me edit#1 for a sound indicator.

Comment: Good point with the sound indicator. My original question is updated, as well is the code. Still the same problem...

Comment: @TheisKristensen - Try removing the 2 export DLLAPI definitions GetMsgProc and NewWndProc in the dll.h, these functions should not be exported, only hook/unhook function pair need to.

Comment: Done - same problem. No noise in the GetMsgProc.

Comment: Strange, could be the new security stuffs that is added in the newer OS. I actually tested out your code and modify it until it works (the click message appears) before I answer the question, but I am running WinXP. Last suggestion, debug the `hookNotepad` and see whether every api call is successful.

Comment: If have debugged the ´hookNotepad´ and all calls are succesful. One thing I was thinking about is that I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, and I guess that notepad.exe is x64 as well. I haven't made any change to the configuration in visual studio, so I guess that the win32 program is made in 32 bit?? But if this is the case then the SetWindowsHookEx should NOT be succesful (but it is)..

Comment: I think the logical answer is that you cannot mix 32-bit and 64-bit binary modules in the memory of a single process, they are completely different in memory layout. The hook/subclass api is actually just redirecting the call from the original procedure to the new one, supplied by the user, without any modification to the the calling interface. And knowing that the calling convention of 32/64 bit are different, this is just not possible. You can further test that your code does work with windows applets by copying a notepad.exe from a 32-bit Win7.

Comment: Your right - problem solved. The standard notepad.exe in win 7 is a 64 bit application. In the folder under C:\Windows\SysWOW64 there is another version of notepad.exe, it's the 32 bit. This also shows in the task manager. After running the 32 bit version of notepad it works! Thank you VERY much for you help and time!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in the context of the hooked process.  Your hookNotepad() function runs in a different process and thus your WndProc() function is in a different address space.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was doing this already (?) When I injected my dll file (with the hookNotepad() function in it), I thought the dll file was in the notepad process. The screendump i attached shows that the dll file gets loaded in notepad, right? Can you give an example on how to inject the hookNotepad() function in the right address space?

Comment: It does get loaded in notepad.exe, but you are still calling SetWindowLongPtr() in hookNotepad() which is running in your hooker executable.  You need to call SetWindowLongPtr() in the context of notepad.exe, which in this case can be done in the hook (which it appears you are already doing in MsgProc).

Comment: The problem is that the GetMsgProc function never gets called. I mean the 2 parameter of SetWindowsHook is GetMsgProc, which are a pointer to the hook procedure. This procedure/function should be called when notepad get a message posted to the message queue(notepads message queue), right? So any notepad message (e.g WM_ACTIVATE) should trigger the GetMsgProc function........ but it doesn't